# How to concat numeric and string value in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, aggregation-framework, concatenation

I need to select a value from an array in a json file in mongodb.

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "key" : {
        "subkey" : "value",
        "subkey1" : "value",
        "subkey2" : "value",
        "firstArray" : [ 
            NumberLong(1234),
            "secondIndex"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to select firstIndex, my query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        columnName: {
            $concat: [{
                $substr: ["$key.firstArray[0]"],
                "hello world"
            }
            ]
       }
   }
}])
```

But this returns an empty string. I don't understand why.

The other thing I tried was using $arrayElemAt, which looks like:

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        columnName: {
            $concat: [{
                $arrayElemAt: ["$key.firstArray", 0],
                "hello world"
            }]
       }
   }
}])
```

But this returns a concat only supports strings, not NumberLongs.

Comment: No concatenation needed here. Try `db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        columnName: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$key.firstArray", 0]
            }
   }
}])`

Comment: But I need to append the result onto a string that I want, I guess I didn't specify in the original question, I'm updating it now

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        columnName: {
            $concat: [{$substr:[{
                $arrayElemAt: ["$key.firstArray", 0]
            }, 0, -1]},
            "hello world"]
       }
   }
}])`

Comment: It's not working for me, robomongo keeps telling me error line 12 unexpected token. Where my arrayelemAt starts.

Comment: Please copy paste code from my last comment. Your code has syntax errors.

Comment: Nevermind it works now as it is.... wow thanks a ton!! Do you want to answer it below so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `$toString` from mongo 4.0 version.

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([
 {"$project":{
   "columnName":{
     "$concat":[
       {"$toString":{"$arrayElemAt":["$key.firstArray",0]}},
       "hello world"
     ]
   }
 }}
])
```

You can try below query to `$concat` long and string value. Use `$substr` to convert the computed long value to string.

```
db.getCollection('table_name').aggregate([
 {"$project":{
   "columnName":{
     "$concat":[
       {"$substr":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$key.firstArray",0]},0,-1]},
       "hello world"
     ]
   }
 }}
])
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much, I had my hello world within the concat curly bracket